# Put legend for all lines on the matplolit

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm running this code to plot a graph with two-axis but I'm getting an issue to display the legend for each line plotted on for the lines for the "first axis".

```
#create some mark data
temp=weather.head(4)
temp.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
temp=temp.transpose()
temp_label=list(ppt.head(0))
#display(ppt)

ppt=weather.tail(1)
ppt.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
ppt=ppt.transpose()
#display(temp)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
color='tab:red'
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature', color=color)
ax1.plot(temp.index, temp.loc[:,:], label=['A','B','C','D'])
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
leg = ax1.legend(loc='upper left', fancybox=True, shadow=True)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)


ax2 = ax1.twinx()

color = 'tab:grey'
ax2.set_ylabel('Precipitation (mm)', color='grey')
ax2.plot(ppt.index, ppt.loc[:,:], color='grey')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='grey')
leg = ax2.legend(loc='upper right', fancybox=True, shadow=False)
leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
temp.plot(ax=ax1)
```

instead of

```
ax1.plot(temp.index, temp.loc[:,:], label=['A','B','C','D'])
```